# Tethering Not working

Tags: networking, tethering

if I enable Tethering (wifi/usb):

- my phone and the pc can share files on the local net ( phone - pc )
- but the Internet connection is not shared at all

How can I debug/fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

After enabling Tethering follow the steps below:

1. On the Android phone, press Home, press Menu, and touch Settings to open the  Settings application.
2. Touch Wireless & networks > Tethering & portable hotspot.
3. Check USB tethering.

Comment: Hey reply me if still have a problem  with usb tethering.

Comment: I will check and let you know.
Is it possible that there are some limitation on my data connection to avoid Tethering ?

Comment: If I got you: I should fist enable Wifi tethering and then enable usb tethering ? is it some workaround for a known issue ? I mean I know how to enable tethering ...

Comment: Okay , so still u have issue with it or it's resolved?

Comment: no lucky here: same issue